# using Backbone.Collection.get(id) restfully

Tags: collections, backbone.js

It seems like at the moment when I call get on a backbone.js collection, it passes the id by cookie rather than restfully passing into my GET method.  In the Request Header it's coming up like this:

> Cookie:posts=ag5kZXZ-c29jcmVuY2h1c3IOCxIIUG9zdExpc3QYAQw;
>   dev_appserver_login="test100@example.com:False:114323764255192059842"

This is what I have:

The get call:

```
postCollection.get(id)
```

and the get method:

```
def get(self, id):
```

I want to use the id in the get method rather than having to use the cookie.

Comment: you want to use `fetch` to retrieve items from a remote server.  `get` returns a specific model already in the collection.  it will do it via the URL automatically - you have to do nothing.

Comment: I want to get a specific model, and if it doesn't exist, I want my database to add that model in.  I just can't figure out how to get the id to get properly sent from my client to my server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best way to accomplish this is something like the following.

```
var model = collection.get(id);
// If the model is not present locally..
if (!model) {
  // Add empty model with id.
  model = collection.add([{id: id}]);
  // Populate model attributes from server.
  model.fetch({success: successCallback, error: errorCallback });
}
```

`collection.get(id)` shouldn't be making a request to the backend.

Comment: If it's not in the collection, it's going to have to be retrieved, and thus a callback of some sort will be involved to actually look at the model (and there will also need to be one for failure).  Or, if you're using jQuery, you could have the method return a promise object that eventually gets resolved with the model or rejected.

Comment: I'm actually kinda curious how `collection.add([{id: id}]);` works with this, now that I think of it...

Comment: `model.fetch` supports callbacks. I've updated the example to include them. `collection.add` adds a new model to the collection with the attributes passed to it. In this case `id` is the only attribute as the rest are on the server. The `id` has to be present so that `model.fetch` knows to do an HTTP `GET /resource/id` request.

Comment: do you want to add a model to your collection though?  Thinking about it more, what if that id doesn't exist on the server?  Cleanup...

Comment: You could also switch the order. Create a new model with the ID, fetch details from the server, if successful add the model to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on it.  Rather than creating a mostly empty model and then adding attributes to it from the server after fetch, you could do what i pasted below.  One thing to think about with the above example, if you create a model and then try to fetch that ID from the server and it doesn't exist, you'll have to clean it up.  The code below will save you that step.

```
myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url : function() {
     /*
     create _ POST   /model
     read _ GET   /model[/id]
     update _ PUT   /model/id
     delete _ DELETE   /model/id
     */
     return this.id ? '/model/' + this.id : '/model';
   },
});


myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: myModel,
  url: function() {
    return '/model';
  },
  comparator: function(model) {
    return model.get("foo");
  },
  getOrFetch: function(id) {
    var model = this.get(id) || this.getByCid(id);
    if (model) return model;
      var url = this.url() +"/"+ id
      return new this.model().fetch({url:url});
  }
});



var mc = new myCollection(new myModel({foo:"bar"}));
mc.getOrFetch(1)
```